# How to set a background bitmap to a rect or rectF?

Tags: android, canvas

Is there a way to set a background image for a rectangle drawn in a canvas ?
For exemple i have the following onDraw method :

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    this.setBackgroundGradient();
    RectF rect = new RectF();
    rect.set(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), 50);
    canvas.drawRoundRect(rect, 0, 0, this.paint);
}

private void setBackgroundGradient()
{
    this.paint.setShader(new LinearGradient(0, 0,0, getHeight(), 0xff919191, 0xff424242, Shader.TileMode.MIRROR));
}
```

I would like to change my gradient by a background image (repeatable if possible).

Note : i would rather to keep rectangle and not use drawBitmap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Rect is not a drawable, it is a convenience class and only holds the four values that define the rect. Canvas knows how to draw a rect with the Paint object you give it. 
If you want to have a background (image) instead of a rect, then you either use drawBitmap on the canvas or have a (bitmap)drawable that you pass the canvas to when drawing.